# assigning csv file to a variable name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file, i uses pandas to read the .csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
data=read_csv('input.csv')
print(data) 

          0             1             2             3             4             5         
0     -3.288733e-08  2.905263e-08  2.297046e-08  2.052534e-08  3.767194e-08  4.822049e-08  
1      2.345769e-07  9.462636e-08  4.331173e-08  3.137627e-08  4.680112e-08  6.067109e-08 
2     -1.386798e-07  1.637338e-08  4.077676e-08  3.339685e-08  5.020153e-08  5.871679e-08  
3     -4.234607e-08  3.555008e-08  2.563824e-08  2.320405e-08  4.008257e-08  3.901410e-08
4      3.899913e-08  5.368551e-08  3.713510e-08  2.367323e-08  3.172775e-08  4.799337e-08
```

My aim is to assign the file to a column name so that i can access the data in later time. For example by doing something like

```
new_data= df['filename']
                                                                           filename
0     -3.288733e-08,2.905263e-08,2.297046e-08,2.052534e-08,3.767194e-08,4.822049e-08  
1      2.345769e-07,9.462636e-08,4.331173e-08,3.137627e-08,4.680112e-08, 6.067109e-08 
2     -1.386798e-07,1.637338e-08,4.077676e-08,3.339685e-08,5.020153e-08,5.871679e-08  
3     -4.234607e-08,3.555008e-08,2.563824e-08,2.320405e-08,4.008257e-08,3.901410e-08
4      3.899913e-08,5.368551e-08,3.713510e-08,2.367323e-08,3.172775e-08,4.799337e-08
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is it exactly that you want? In your first example, the file/data is asigned to a variable: `data`. You can access it later by using `data` again. Please specify more what it is that you want otherwise.

Comment: i want to assign the data to column name i.e. filename and data should have shape 5x1 for the given example

Comment: i think it is column name

Comment: Still not clear what you want. Can you explain more on what you mean by 'assign the file to a variable name'?

Comment: actually not variable, its a column name

Comment: But why assign it to a colum as strings without the column seperation on the comma's? You could more easily assign the dataframe `data` to a list or a dictionary and then access the dataframe again later on...

Comment: ok sir i am new to pandas i donot have more ideas, please suggest a solution which will be easier

Comment: Do you want to aggregate all columns to one?

Comment: yes u r right @HiranHasanka

Comment: Do you want each record of the unique column is a string or an array/list?

Comment: it should be array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like it (and I still don't completely get the point), but you could just read in your data as 1 column (by using a 'wrong' seperator) and renaming the column.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'input.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
df.columns = [filename]
```

If you then wish, you could add other files by doing the same thing (with a different name for `df` at first) and then concatenate that with `df`.

A more usefull approach IMHO would be to add the dataframe to a dictionary (or a list would be possible).

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'input.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
data_dict = {filename: df}
# ... Add multiple files to data_dict by repeating steps above in a loop
```

You can then access your data later on by calling `data_dict[filename]` or `data_dict['input.csv']`